# BeautifulSoup - Nested Div and Class issues

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A little new to python and webscraping - hopefully its just something i'm missing syntactically.  Tried reading through a similar question, but the elements within the source I'm crawling might be a little different.  Trying to in essence scrape 3 elements:

'Studio'
'386 SQ. FT. | Starting at $1030 Per Monthly Installment' and,
'1030' from the following:

```
<div class="fp-info has-description">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="fp-title col-lg-7">
                                <h4 class="title">Studio</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fp-avil col-lg-5">
                                <p class="small fp-avail-sum"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Available</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <p>386 SQ. FT. | Starting at $1030 Per Monthly Installment</p>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="fp-description">

                                <div class="icon-box effect small clean">
                                    <div class="icon"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></div>

                                    <p class="text-uppercase"><small>Smart Housing Only.</small></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

and the code I'm using to scrape this is:

```
def scrape(key, val):
    if 'http' not in val:
        val = 'http://' + val
    plans = []
    try:
        soup = getWebData(val)
    except:
        plans
    for plan in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'fp-info has-description'}):
        room_type = plan.find(class_="title").text
        price = plan.find('p').text.strip()
        price_formatted = '$'.join(re.findall(r'\d+,?\d+\.\d+',price))
        plans.append((room_type))
    return plans
```

EDIT - the full traceback error I get is: 
for plan in scrape(key,keyLinkMap[key]): File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Python Tests\edrScraper.py", line 40, in scrape
for plan in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'fp-info has-description'}):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment

Any thoughts?  I have a similar scraper that I was bequeathed that does something very similar but it works just fine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you explain your exception handling rationale?

Comment: Include the complete traceback error message in the question please. It'll be easier to debug.

Comment: The problem here is most likely that you are getting an error at the line `soup=getWebData(val)`. For this reason python moves to the `except` which is just `plans`. For that reason, `soup` has never been defined. and so in the line starting `for plan` you have this variable soup which is being referenced, before its been assigned.

Comment: I would also echo the other comments, about a full traceback error being useful, meaning we don't need to guess, and the rationale for the exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these lines:

```
try:
    soup = getWebData(val)
except:
    plans
```

When `getWebData(val)` throws an exception, the variable `soup` doesn't get assigned any value. So, when you use it here `soup.find_all(...)`, you are using a variable `soup` which is not yet defined. Thus the message "local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment".

You can rectify this by doing something like this

```
try:
    soup = getWebData(val)
except:
    return plans
```

Here, if an exception is thrown, the program won't reach the `soup.find_all(...)` statement.

Comment: Thanks!  The only problem is - it shouldn't throw an exception when fed the data of the studio for $1030 - it should return that data.

Comment: I did not understand what your problem is now, but the `UnboundLocalError` problem should be solved by doing this change.

Comment: Also, I can't say `why it is throwing an exception` since I don't know what you've written in the `getWebData` function.

Comment: apologies! def getWebData(link):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text,'html.parser')

Comment: The only thing that can go wrong with that function is that the link is not a valid url. Check what the error is by printing it in the `except` block.